# Comparison of unbalanced groups of values

Tags: anova, normal-distribution, variance, group-differences

I know there are several questions (here and on other websites) regarding the comparison of values, but I am still lost with the data I have and the analyses I should conduct.

I have just 18 values (home range areas) and I want to compare them twice: first between study sites and then by gender (male/female), to see if there are significant differences in home range areas within these groups. I would also like to consider the interaction between Study.site*Gender.
Here is the data:

```
    ID  Area    Study.site  Gender
    v1  6.558201      1      0
    v2  3.274141      2      0
    v3  4.841487      2      0
    v4  6.419502      2      0
    v5  2.351595      3      0
    v6  1.104536      3      0
    v7  3.687818      3      0
    v8  3.708099      3      0
    v9  4.198809      3      0
    v10 3.831449      4      0
    v11 5.547973      5      0
    v12 7.731753      1      1
    v13 1.772005      2      1
    v14 2.433105      2      1
    v15 2.142429      3      1
    v16 1.918333      4      1
    v17 1.951922      4      1
    v18 3.740321      5      1
```

I fitted a linear model, after a "sqrt" transformation of the "area" values (since they were not normally distributed):

```
test.1 <- lm(Area ~ Study.site*Type, data = data1)
```

Then I believe an ANOVA would be good to test these differences, but I am having trouble with the assumptions; I tested first for the residuals and it looks that they are not normally distributed.

```
> test1.res <- resid(test.1)
> shapiro.test(test1.res)

Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  test1.res
W = 0.88702, p-value = 0.03432
```

My main questions are: 1) is the ANOVA actually a good way to obtain the results I want, considering the (few) data? If so, 2) how should I solve the normality issue?

Comment: Can you clarify what your research question is? It seems a bit strange to investigate the impact of study site and study type on area.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement, please check the changes I made in the question. I hope it is clearer now!

Comment: This post should help get you started. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless